Existence of series $\{x_n \}^{\infty}_{n=1} \to \infty$ such that $\sum^{\infty}_{0}f (x_n)$ converges
One question from homework:

Let the function $f(x)$ be such that $f(x)$ is non-negative and continuous on $[1,\infty)$.
And the integral $\int^{\infty}_{1}f(x)dx$ converges. Then prove that there is series $\{x_n \}^{\infty}_{n=1} \to \infty$ such that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}f(x_n)$ converges.


$\textbf{My attempt:}$
I created a series of intervals such that $\{I_n \}^{\infty}_{n=1}=[n,n+1]$ where $f$ is continuous because $[n,n+1] \subseteq [1,\infty).$
Then, based on Weierstrass,  I created series $f(x_n) = \min_{x \in [n, n+1]} f(x)$ which it easy to see that $x_n \geq n$ and therefore $x_n \to \infty$, and we have
$$\int^{\infty}_{1}f(x)dx=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\int^{n+1}_{n}f(x)dx \geq \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\int^{n+1}_{n}f(x_n)dx=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}f(x_n)$$
And since the left side converges and $f$ is non-negative, we have  $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}f(x_n)$ converges

$\textbf{Question:}$
I've been told that's wrong because $f(x)$ not necessarily decreasing, so I'm asking how can I solve this. Thanks!

You probably meant to put $\int_n^{n+1}$ in the series in your inequality, but otherwise I don't see what's wrong with your approach.

I'm lazy; I'd probably directly apply the integral test for (series) convergence.

Also, $f$ need not be decreasing.  Take whatever decreasing $f$ you imagine is required.  Then $f(x)|\sin(x)|$ is not decreasing and gives a convergent integral (by comparison with the original integral because $0 \leq |\sin(x)| \leq 1$).

Since the integral converges, we know the following:
$$ \forall \epsilon > 0, n \in \mathbb{N} \,\exists\, x > n: f(x) \le \epsilon $$
This is due to the fact that, if this weren't the case, we would have
$$ \exists \epsilon > 0, n \in \mathbb{N} \forall x > n: f(x) > \epsilon $$
which would contradict the convergence of the integral.
Thus, setting $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2^n}$, we can choose $x_n > n$ such that $0 \leq f(x_n) \leq \frac{1}{2^n}$.
Since $x_n>n$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = +\infty$. Furthermore, we know
$$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty  f(x_n) \leq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = 1$$
Since $f(x_n) \geq 0$, this implies the convergence of the series.

Not true. $f$ might have increasingly narrow and high spikes so that the integral converges but $\max(f)\to\infty$. For example, if $f(x)=n$ for $n\le x \le 1/n^3$ and zero otherwise then $\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx=1/n^2$ and the sum of these converges.

@martycohen I don't quite understand what you mean, could you elaborate?

It is not true that the integral converging implies that the function goes to zero. If the function is monotonic, yes.

@martycohen I don't state that the function goes to 0. I state that I can choose single points where the function is very small.

So continuity is not even required here.
